# How do you make a Save button work in Laravel (DataTables)?

Tags: php, html, laravel, visual-studio-code, datatables

How do i go about creating a php function in my controller which saves a certain row indicated by a checkbox? This row of data will need to be appended to an SQL database when a submit button is clicked. This is what i have tried so far, but it doesnt seem to work

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@include('partialViews.navigation')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
@yield('navigation')
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="card">
<table id="example" class="data-table table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col"></th>
<th scope="col">Stage</th>
<th scope="col">Bedrijf</th>
<th scope="col">Afdeling</th>
<th scope="col">Locatie</th>
<th scope="col">Periode</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach ($stagevoorstelen as $key => $stagevoorstel) 
<tr>
<td scope="row">
<div class="form-check">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tableMaterialCheck2">
</div>
</td>
<td>{{$stagevoorstel->assignment->title ?? "stagair"}}</td>
<td>{{$stagevoorstel->companyContact1->department->company->name}}</td>
<td>{{$stagevoorstel->companyContact1->department->name ?? ""}}</td>
<td>{{$stagevoorstel->companyContact1->department->company->city}}</td>
<td>{{$stagevoorstel->assignment->year ?? ""}}  {{$stagevoorstel->assignment->semester ?? ""}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach 
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="buttontjes">
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" id="btn-save" value="create" class="btn  btn-sm">opslaan</button></td>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is the controller I have no idea what to put in my function!

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\StageVoorstelRepository;
class student_bekijkstagesController extends Controller
{
    /** 
     * @var StagevoorstelRepository
     */
    private $stageVoorstel;
    /**
     * kaartjesWeergevenTestController Constructor
     *  
     * @param StageVoorstelRepository $stagevoorstel
     */
    public function __construct(StageVoorstelRepository $stageVoorstel)
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
        $this->stageVoorstel = $stageVoorstel;
    }
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('student_bekijkstages',['stagevoorstelen' => $this->stageVoorstel->getAvailableForStudents()]);
    }
    public function save(Request $request){
        if($request->submit == "Save"){
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see form html tag. Is it included in view??

Comment: I haven't used it!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using a form, you can utilize JS to collect the `checked row` with the data, and `POST` it via a JS method or Jquery's `.post()` to your backend PHP, so the data can be saved in DB

There are examples like this one: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42290/getting-the-checked-rows-in-datatables
which describe how from Datatables you ca get the checked row and work with it..
The Datatables documentation also has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any form tag.

```html
<form action="{{route ('route_name')}}" method="route_method">
...
</form>
```

Also you need @csrf for post,put,... methods .

Comment: is this an actual answer? or more of a Comment? Please use Comments to clarify the case, then propose actual helpful Answers.

Comment: @Ron it's an answer. Which one is easier? Just adding form tag or write lines of extra code in js???